# Searching for a specific string connected to an attribute of an attribute of a list?

Tags: python

I probably worded that title terribly, so here's an explanation:
I have two classes, Tile and Grid.
Within Tile I have created a base tile format, with its position, name and items.
Within Grid, I use for loops to create those tiles properly and add information and store them all within "grid"
I want to allow the user to search for the tile within the grid for which tile has the attribute "name" that is equal to what the user has attempted to search for, and then return all of the information (x and y positions, "name" and "items" attributes).

```
global grid

letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]

class Tile:
    def __init__(self, x, y, name=None, items="Empty"):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.contents = {
            "name": name,
            "items": items
        }

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.contents)

class Grid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = []
        self.resetGrid()

    def resetGrid(self):
        grid = [[Tile(x, y) for x in range(9)] for y in range(9)]
        for n in range(9):
            letter = letters[n]
            for m in range(9):
                grid[n][m].contents = {"name":letter + str(m+1),"items":"Empty"}
        return grid

    def printGrid(self):
        for row in grid:
            print()
            print("-" * 44)
            for tile in row:
                name = tile.contents["name"]
                #items = tile.contents["items"]
                print(name, end=" | ")
        print()
        print("-" * 44)

    def searchGrid(self):
        grid = self.resetGrid()
        print()
        print("")
        print("Please select which square you wish to see the information about.")
        userinput = input("> ")
        for name in tile.contents["name"]:
            pring("k")

newgrid = Grid()
newgrid.printGrid()

#newgrid.resetGrid()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do not include code as an image or a link.  It belongs as text in your question.  See [mcve]

Comment: @user3483203 - I fixed that already for Jordan

Comment: Why does your file have a Ruby extension? (.rb)

Comment: I'll point out that the fourth from the last line reads `pring`, rather than `print`. These mistakes are harder to make in an editor that has syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply search each tile for the name until you have found it. Is this what you are looking for?

```
def searchGrid(self):
        grid = self.resetGrid()
        print()
        print("")
        print("Please select which square you wish to see the information about.")
        userinput = input("> ")
        for row in self.grid:
            for tile in row:
                 if tile.contents['name'] == userinput:
                       print(tile.contents)
                       #other things
                       break
```

Also note typos:

Change `pring` to `print`

Change `grid` to `self.grid` in `printGrid()` method

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]

class Tile:
    def __init__(self, x, y, name=None, items="Empty"):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.contents = {
            "name": name,
            "items": items
        }

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.contents)

class Grid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = []
        self.resetGrid()

    def resetGrid(self):
        self.grid = [[Tile(x, y) for x in range(9)] for y in range(9)]
        for n in range(9):
            letter = letters[n]
            for m in range(9):
                self.grid[n][m].contents = {"name":letter + str(m+1),"items":"Empty"}

    def printGrid(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            print()
            print("-" * 44)
            for tile in row:
                name = tile.contents["name"]
                #items = tile.contents["items"]
                print(name, end=" | ")
        print()
        print("-" * 44)

    def searchGrid(self):
        print()
        print("")
        print("Please select which square you wish to see the information about.")
        userinput = input("> ")
        for n in range(9):
            for m in range(9):
                if userinput == self.grid[n][m].contents['name']:
                    print(self.grid[n][m].x)
                    print(self.grid[n][m].y)
                    print(self.grid[n][m].contents['name'])
                    print(self.grid[n][m].contents['items'])


newgrid = Grid()
newgrid.printGrid()
newgrid.searchGrid()
```